# What is instead of an action in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Suppose I want to have my program to react same way, say, navigate to next record, in response to different events, including pressing a key, clicking GUI button, selecting menu item and so on.

This was done with "actions" in Swing.

Can I materialize this concept in some program object in JavaFX?

Or I should make a porridge of interacting objects?

Comment: By "actions", do you mean [javax.swing.Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Action is still there in JavaFX. Example belows how to create an action, bind it to a keyboard shortcut and share between two different elements.

```
Button go = new Button("Go");

EventHandler<ActionEvent> goAction = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
        browser.load(location.getText(), new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("---------------");
                System.out.println(browser.getHTML());
            }
        });
    }
};

...

MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Go!");
menuItem.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.G, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));

go.setOnAction(goAction);
menuItem.setOnAction(goAction);
```

Comment: Suppose I want to `System.out.println("click!");` not just in response to button, but also in response to menu select and keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX provides many events. You also do this with `setOn()` method:

```
button.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
       // code here
    }
});
```